# Which Is Faster: Outputting Two Different String Or Adding Both Strings Together (C++)

Tags: c++, string, performance, io

Sorry if this really doesn't make sense, but I'm curious if it matters.
Which is faster:

```
std::cout << String1 << String2;
```

Or:

```
string String2 = "Some Text" + String1;
std::cout << String2;
```

Comment: What's preventing you from benchmarking it?

Comment: How would I be able to achive that?

Comment: Read e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044422/how-can-i-benchmark-the-performance-of-c-code

Comment: I guess writing to stream would be faster.

Comment: sorry for wasting time.? Although idk how i'd implement that

Comment: Write a program (or function) using the first method. Write another program (or a different function in the same program) using the second method. Run them both and see which is quicker. You'll probably need to run them both lots of times to get useful, stable measurements, but the linked question goes into all that.

Comment: If you want to know which is faster, use a benchmark tool like this one: https://quick-bench.com/

Comment: This might depend on a lot of variables. Maybe it depends on the length of the strings, on how the stream is implemented in the standard library you are using, maybe even on what the stream pipes to. It's possible that one of these approaches it always better than the other, but more likely than not there exists circumstances where one is better, and other circumstances where the other is better.

Comment: IMHO, printing the strings is faster.  When concatenating strings, the end of the string has to be located, then the second string is appended.  The string may have to perform memory reallocation.  Printing a string is a one pass endeavor without any memory allocations.

Comment: Almost same: https://quick-bench.com/q/FVVX0Uns5Lf8GNYM0SRjxyiiIgs Summing strings minimally better.

Comment: Did you mean the first case to be  `std::cout << "Some Text" << String1;` by chance? It doesn't look like we're comparing apples to apples.

Comment: Wanted to minimize the amount of time writting.

Comment: Just actually realized i think that was intentional, although i don't know why.

Comment: This question still is left unanswered stackoverflow wise